# My notification badge icon is not showing after the PWA is installed to homescreen

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a mobile website which has the ability to receive push notifications. Some codes on the firebase-messaging-sw.js are as below,

```
 messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  var notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: payload.data.icon,
    data: payload.data.click_action,
    badge: "{icon url}",
    image: payload.data.image,
    tag: payload.data.unique_id
  };


  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

When I allow notifications on the mobile Chrome, the notifications are showing perfectly, which my custom made badge logo showing on the notification bar. But after I click on "Add to Homescreen", the notification badge icon becomes the default bell-shaped icon. Why is it like that and is there any ways to change it?

Thank you.

Comment: the value of badge seems to be a string, "{icon url}" to be exact.  That should be full path URL to the icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in Chrome. They have already fixed it [in this commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/21447c9d90951d0bded1a7a0c2ae29389d50b6eb).

The bugfix is rolling out with Chrome 69 on the 4th of September (tomorrow). You can check the rollout state here: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule